# How to join tables over multiple databases/schema in django orm?

Tags: mysql, django, database, django-orm, multiple-databases

I am new to django, and I have started the process of moving an existing API to Django. The current API has multiple databases.
For example, table `account` is in database `A`, table `notification` is in database `B` etc.
It is a legacy database on which the app is running, and as such, I cannot change the database.
For explanations sake, the structure of both are -

**Account Table**

```
+-----+--------------+
| id  | account_name |
+-----+--------------+
| 123 | John         |
+-----+--------------+
| 124 | Henry        |
+-----+--------------+
| 126 | Vlad         |
+-----+--------------+
```

**Notification Table**

```
+----+------------+-----------------------------------+
| id | account_id | notification_body                 |
+----+------------+-----------------------------------+
| 1  | 123        | Someone sent you a message        |
+----+------------+-----------------------------------+
| 2  | 123        | Someone commented on your photo   |
+----+------------+-----------------------------------+
| 3  | 126        | Someone sent you a friend request |
+----+------------+-----------------------------------+
```

In the above tables, `notification`.`account_id` is a foreign key with relation to `account`.`id`, which is the primary key in the `account` table. I want to join both the tables, the equivalent of the following SQL query.

```
SELECT * FROM A.account AS acc 
JOIN B.notification ON noti ON noti.account_id = acc.id
```

Django uses foreign key to join tables using the `select_related()` function. Now, the problem is, I have foreign keys which are not limited to a single database. But, django as of now does not support foreign keys over multiple databases. So, how do we join those tables that are in another database in Django if foreign key related joins is not feasible?

Remember that both the tables are in separate databases.